# Adding img attributes with php

Tags: html

This works:

```
<?php 
     if($user->image > 0)
     {
          $imgSrc = "/uploads/".$user->image;
          echo "Your Current Image:" . "<br>";
          echo "<img src= $imgSrc >";
     }
```

I need to add height and width attributes to the $imgSrc but have been unsuccessful so far.

The image is showing at its original dimensions and I want to change this.

Comment: The value for `src` should be quoted. You then could add in any other attribute before the `>`. Also you are missing the opening `<` for your `img`.

Comment: Just added the < for img. I will try your suggestions now.

Comment: i'll give youa hint... the answer has absolutely nothing to do with php whatsover...

Comment: @Adelphia The answer may have a lot to do with PHP. Jon are you asking how to get the correct width and height of the image?

Comment: php doesn't know anything about html. php only knows strings.

Comment: I made the modification and it still doesn't work:

echo "<img src= $imgSrc height:50 width:50 >";

It's displaying the image in the original dimensions.

Comment: It would be `height="50" width="50"`... or `style="width:50px; height:50px;"`.

Comment: `echo "<img src='$imgSrc' style='height:50px;width:50px;'>";` there ya go, buddy.

Comment: like i said, nothing to do with php.

Comment: More to do with PHP than other questions I've seen; at least PHP is the actual language.

Comment: just because php was used does not mean php was the issue. the issue here is entirely html.

Comment: ...so, it's PHP's fault that his browser doesn't understand `width:50` as an image attribute.... i think you get my point

Comment: "php only knows strings". You seriously underestimate PHP

Comment: @Adelphia also you should edit the question if you find OP posts comments that explains what the question is. It's called helping. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: HTML and PHP are two entirely different standards. The PHP standard is in no way relevant to this question. If you can't understand that then I'm sorry, that's my last attempt at explaining it.. and I don't know why you're welcoming me to SO, if I could edit the question then I obviously wouldn't be new...

Comment: Yes clearly it's not relevant, which I have discovered several minutes after I said it **may** involve PHP. Congratulations on guessing the right side of ambiguity on this one. Anyone can edit a question- changes just need approving.

Comment: Thanks noodles. If you read the comments you'll see I was actually the first person to give him the correct answer.

Comment: Congratulations, I can see you're very proud of guessing correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it transpires that you want to change the size of the image from its original

```
echo "<img src='$imgSrc' style='width: 100px; height:100px;' />";
```

and maybe you want to maintain proportions

```
echo "<img src='$imgSrc' style='width: 100px; height:auto;' />";
```

If you were looking to add the exact size from the image using PHP you would do this

```
if($user->image > 0)
 {
      $imgSrc = "/uploads/".$user->image;
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgSrc);
      $style = 'width: ' . $width . 'px; height: ' . $height . 'px;';
      echo 'Your Current Image: <br />';
      echo '<img src="' . $imgSrc . '" style="' . $style . '" alt="User image" />';
 }
```